# Interface for System.Convert

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is there a built in interface that implements `Convert.ToInt64()`?

I'm trying to mock a class that is responsible for converting a string to a long, but I don't know which interface to use. It doesn't have to be `Convert`.

I can't imaging I'm the only one who needs a testable class that converts strings to longs.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you need to mock the conversion?

Comment: "I can't imaging I'm the only one who needs a testable class that converts strings to longs." - not sure I agree with this.  Convert.ToInt64 and its cousins `Int64.Parse` and `Int64.TryParse` already do that conversion and have presumably been thoroughly tested by Microsoft.  So why do you want to write your own class to do the same thing?

Comment: @Joe Clearly you misunderstand the purpose of an interface when writing unit tests. I want to have an interface so that I can create a mock of the class. This allows me to to verify that the call was made, what parameters were passed, how many times it was called, fake the output to test what happens when try parse passes or fails, and create simpler tests that are not testing the actual output of try parse.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth - it's subjective of course and YMMV, but the benefits you describe have a cost in increased complexity, and I'm generally not keen on mocking low-level stuff like parsing strings, `DateTime.Now` etc.

Answer (score 1):

To help with mocking, do not call `Convert.ToInt64()` directly. Instead, create a simple wrapper interface and use dependency injection:

```
public interface IStringToLong {
   long StringToLong(string val);
}

public class StringToLong : IStringToLong {
   public long StringToLong(string val) => Convert.ToInt64(val); 
}

// While using dependency injection
public class SomeClass {
   private readonly IStringToLong _stringToLong;

   public SomeClass(IStringToLong stringToLong) {
      _stringToLong = stringToLong;
   }

   public void SomeMethod {
       // Instead of Convert.ToInt64("10000"), use this:
       var someLong = _stringToLong.StringToLong("10000");
   }
}
```

Now when testing `SomeClass` you can use a mocked object created from the IStringToLong interface.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert` is a static class, so it cannot have an interface.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do without looking at some code, but if you truly need to mock `Convert.ToInt64`, you could use `Func<string, long>`, then in your tests pass a mock function, i.e. `anyString => 21122`.